# Better way to revert to a previous SVN revision of a file?

Tags: svn

I accidentally committed too many files to an SVN repository and changed some things I didn't mean to. (Sigh.) In order to revert them to their prior state, the best I could come up with was

```
svn rm l3toks.dtx
svn copy -r 854 svn+ssh://<repository URL>/l3toks.dtx ./l3toks.dtx
```

Jeez! Is there no better way? Why can't I just write something like this:

```
svn revert -r 854 l3toks.dtx
```

Okay, I'm only using v1.4.4, but I skimmed over the changes list for the 1.5 branch and I couldn't see anything directly related to this. Did I miss anything?

---

Edit: I guess I wasn't clear enough. I don't think I want to reverse merge, because then I'll lose  the changes that I *did* want to make! Say that `fileA` and `fileB` were both modified but I only wanted to commit `fileA`; accidentally typing

```
svn commit -m "small change"
```

commits both files, and now I want to roll back `fileB`. Reverse merging makes this task no easier (as far as I can tell) than the steps I outlined above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I revert an SVN commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13330011/how-do-i-revert-an-svn-commit)

Answer (score 242, accepted):

```
svn merge -r 854:853 l3toks.dtx
```

or

```
svn merge -c -854 l3toks.dtx
```

The two commands [are equivalent](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.merge.html).

Comment: Ah, finally I see the relevant part in `svn help merge` (usage #3). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this, just wanted to state something - say, I'm at revision 855, I want to revert a file to revision 854. If I do `svn merge -c -854 my.file`, and then do `svn diff`, it seems to show one revision before 854 (that is, 853); only when I do `svm merge -c 854 myfile` (without the `-`), it looks like myfile is reverted to rev 854. Thanks again, cheers!

Comment: Is there a reason why the first option above worked like a charm for me while the second one didn't work AT ALL?

Comment: Don't forget to commit after reverse merging, though. I often forget :)

Comment: Really should minus 1 this for not stating what the difference between these two commands is. Poor answer

Comment: @sprog - if there is a difference I'd appreciate knowing

Comment: If you're just undoing the last commit to a file, as compared to your WC version, `svn merge -r BASE:PREV filename` should work, right?

Comment: @orip from `svn help merge`:  "'-c M' is equivalent to '-r <M-1>:M', and '-c -M' does the reverse: '-r M:<M-1>'."

Comment: @ErichBSchulz that's correct, and therefore the two commands are equivalent.

Comment: @skybondsor maybe you forgot the dash in "-854"? Just happened to me

Comment: @skybondsor - and why aren't you happy, when any option works? To answer your question: probably it's time for you to upgrade svn client. `merge -c` was not always there.

Comment: before committing changes, you could want to check if the file is like it was in the desired revision, so using `svn diff -r <version_number> <file>`

Comment: The first line (svn merge -r 854:853 l3toks.dtx) will rollback to v853, I can see result after `svn status` and I can `svn commit`, but the second won't (I cannot see anything after `svn status`, but the file has been rollbacked), so they not the same, svn v1.6.11

Answer (score 34):

Check out "[undoing changes](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo)" section of the [svn book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/)

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Answer (score 32):

sorry to use up some space on just a reiteration of the previously given answer - but this is something I always end up in trouble with.

Let's say I've updated the local files to the latest revision, which is 854. Then, I'd want to get an older revision - the version of the file from few revision earlier, say revision 851.

Copy would work:

```
svn copy -r 851 svn+ssh://<repository URL>/l3toks.dtx ./l3toks.dtx
```

.. however, I can't be bothered grepping for the repo URL :)

Update seemingly might work:

```
svn up -r 851 ./l3toks.dtx
```

... however, it also marks the local copy as "freshly checked out", or rather "same as online revision" (i.e. in Tortoise/RabbitVCS you get a green OK checkmark) - which means you cannot do `svn ci -m "rolled back to r 851"`: simply because the local `subversion` executable won't notice any local changes, and won't be bothered to upload anything to the online repository.

And, as already answered, reverse merge works - but in this case, one shouldn't rely on shortcut syntax; but specifically state:

```
svn merge -r HEAD:851 l3toks.dtx
--- Reverse-merging r854 through r852 into 'l3toks.dtx':
U    l3toks.dtx
```

I must admit - I would never understand the sentence "*Reverse-merging r854 through r852 into file*" to mean "*Just got r851 of your file, and overwritten whatever you had previously locally - and it is marked as different from latest online revision, so you can check it back in online as a new 'rollback' revision*", but I guess (and hope :) ) that is what it does :)

After this, one can use `svn diff` for a quick make-sure if we got the right revision back locally; and also, the file will be marked with a red exclamation mark in Tortoise/RabbitVCS (that is, different from latest committed version), and so `svn ci -m "rolled back to r 851"` can run this time.

Also, note that if you, finally, change your mind after reverse merging (*i.e. you anyways want to keep working on the latest, HEAD revision, here 854 - after you have rolled back to 851 locally, but haven't yet committed the rollback*), you shouldn't use `svn up`, because it will simply say that it is already "*At revision 854*"; use instead `svn revert --recursive .` or similar...

Cheers!

Ref: [How to Roll Back Changes using Subversion - Jacob Wright – Flex, AIR, PHP, etc.](http://jacwright.com/blog/75/how-to-roll-back-changes-using-subversion/)

EDIT: ... and apparently, the exactly same effect as `svn merge -r HEAD:851 l3toks.dtx`, can be achieved with:

```
svn export -r 851 l3toks.dtx
A    l3toks.dtx
Export complete.
```

Comment: You should ALWAYS prefer svn export, since it does exactly what you want - check out a File in a certain revision, while reverse Merging will also try and merge your local changes with the specified version, it is a complex and crazy operation, which is prone to errors if you don't watch out!

Comment: I had problems with reverse merging. Rather than figure out why, I just tried export and it worked perfectly. I would highly recommend just using export. You can use `--force` to overwrite directories. Just remember it will overwrite any changes.

Comment: Very good explanation about what is actually happening! I use AnkhSVN and TortoiseSVN frequently, and I don't see anywhere to make use of ``svn export`` - am I missing something or is that just not implemented in these GUIs?

Comment: @Conrad, You use that by clicking "Export..." in AnkhSVN and "Export" in TortoiseSVN from your repository context(right-click) menu

Answer (score 10):

I recently had to revert to a particular revision to debug an older build and this worked like magic:

```
svn up -r 3340 (or what ever your desired revision number)
```

I had to resolve all conflicts using "tc" option as I did not care about local changes (checked in everything I cared about prior to reverting)

To get back to head revision was simple too:

```
svn up
```

Answer (score 5):

What you're looking for is called a "reverse merge".  You should consult the docs regarding the merge function in the SVN book (as luapyad, or more precisely the first commenter on that post, points out).  If you're using Tortoise, you can also just go into the log view and right-click and choose "revert changes from this revision" on the one where you made the mistake.

Answer (score 4):

Reverse merge is exactly what you want (see luapyad's answer).  Just apply the merge to the erroneously-commited file instead of the entire directory.

Answer (score 4):

If you only want to undo the last checkin, you can use the following

```
svn merge -r head:prev l3toks.dtx
```

That way, you don't have to hunt for the current and previous version numbers.

Answer (score 4):

svn merge will merge revisions, not revert them. i.e. if you have some addition in your HEAD version then merge that with a previous revision, then the change will persist.

I use svn cat then redirect it into the file:

```
svn cat -r 851 l3toks.dtx > l3toks.dtx
```

Then you have the 851 content in that file and can check it back in.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the **Eclipse IDE** with the **SVN plugin** you can do as follows:

1. Right-click the files that you want to revert (or the folder they were contained in, if you deleted them by mistake and you want to add them back)
2. Select "**Team > Switch**"
3. Choose the "Revision" radion button, and enter the revision number you'd like to revert to. Click OK
4. Go to the Synchronize perspective
5. Select all the files you want to revert
6. Right-click on the selection and do "**Override and Commit...**"

This will revert the files to the revision that you want. Just keep in mind that SVN will see the changes as a new commit. That is, the change gets a new revision number, and there is no link between the old revision and the new one. You should specify in the commit comments that you are reverting those files to a specific revision.