# SVN go back revision for a file

Tags: svn

I have committed a file in svn and that file was earlier also committed by different users earlier as I have committed it , i found that I 
have commit ed something wrong in it , so what I have did is that I take a just previous version of it , copy that and committed it to balance the things  and then upon top of it committed my changes and again committed it , please advise it is the rite approach.

Comment: 1.) it should not be a problem that someone else modified the file earlier than you did. That is what a repository is about. 2.) unless you did not use brute force and ignored all hints and warnings your changes should be merged with those prior changes. 3.) if you really have to revert your own comit then take a look at svns `-c` flag which you can use to revert a certain commit by specifying a "negative" revision number in a merge operation. That would be the "most clean" way to revert a commit. Take a look at svns manual (`man svn`) or its help texts (`svn help merge`).

Comment: @arkascha I am using eclipse and I have installed plugin inside it so I can see the history and from history I TOOK THE JUST ONE PREVIOUS changes and copy that in my local and committed to balance the things

Comment: possible duplicate of [Better way to revert to a previous SVN revision of a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/345997/better-way-to-revert-to-a-previous-svn-revision-of-a-file)

Comment: You copied a previous version of a file over the current (so you replaced it) and committed that. This comes out the same as what the "clean" way of reverting does if (only if) there really is no other change in between. I understood this is the case, so you are fine. Except in one situation: if whilst you copied the file and prepared the commit someone else uploads another version. In that case you'd be warned again and you'd have to update your local working copy again. And unless you do not ignore all those warnings and hints you'd be safe again, although this game _might_ go on endlessly.