# TortoiseSVN - Revert produces tree conflicts

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm trying to revert to an old revision of the folder, but it returns an error about 'conflicting modifications' and tree conflicts. Apparently, some files/subfolders where deleted or created since. What I want to do is completely overwrite my current copy with the one from that old revision including all file names etc. How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: You say you are trying to revert. Word "revert" has a special meaning in SVN (it means "forget about all the changes I have made in working copy, and make it so as if I haven't made any changes"). But you should not experience errors with it. It seems that you are doing "update to revision" instead of revert. Could you edit your question and write exactly what actions you are initiating.

Comment: I'm finding a revision in the log and clicking 'revert to this revision'

Comment: I get the tree conflicts too, and I did the same, just finding a revision in the log and clicking 'revert to this revision

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can delete (not on SVN but on your machine) the folder.
After you can take an update (with the version that you want).
Now you have the current version of your folder.

Sam

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need to preform reverse merging for getting the folder reverted to previous revision .

[Better way to revert to a previous SVN revision of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345997/better-way-to-revert-to-a-previous-svn-revision-of-a-file)

**Undoing Changes** section @  http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.   Here is the solution:

Say you have created revisions 1,2,3 and 4.  Perhaps you even have some things in your working copy that would be version 5 if you were to commit them...

You know 2 was working, and 3 and 4 are all full of problems which you or someone else has introduced, and you couldn't care less about those changesets.

What you want is a sort of "undo" to a certain revision.  "Update to Revision" looks like its going to help you, but don't use that.  It just messes up your life.  This tool is basically only good if you want to change one or two files and recompile your program to see if it works because you think you have isolated the files which are the "culprits" to your problem.

However, if you aren't sure and don't care and just want good old version 2 again, here's what you do: (by the way, we will not be able to "delete" versions 3 and 4, but we will create a version 5 which is exacly the same as version 2)

Right click in windows explorer, and choose "show log".  Then select the revision you want (revision 2 in our example) and right click again chose "revert to revision".  A new revision (5) will be created and it will be exactly the same as revision 2.

I must stress that "revert to revision" is an entirely different function than plain old "revert" which simply deletes any files from your working copy which have been modified, and puts back the head (in this case 4).

In a way its similar to "revert to revision" because both are a form of "undo" feature, but revert is risky, since you may loose work!

Hope it helps :)

P.S. This is also called reverse merge, you will note that when you read the status window, the words "reverse merge" occur while svn is working, however the "revert to revision" is doing something behind the scenes for you...

Comment: I get the tree conflicts too like the guy above, and I did the same, just finding a revision in the log and clicking 'revert to this revision